# the table have two columns, one is date and the other is hour, I want to compare the date between '2019-10-23 00' and '2019-10-26 12', how to do?

Tags: mysql

```
select date_format( date, '%Y-%m-%d' ) as date,
            substring(`hour`, 1, 2) as hour,
            sum(revenue) as revenue
        from dsp_platform_country_os_hourly_report as dr
        where concat(substring(dr.`date`, 1, 10), ' ', dr.`hour`)
                between CAST('2019-10-26 0' AS DATE) AND CAST('2019-10-26 15' AS DATE)
        group by date, hour order by dr.date, dr.hour
```

but the sql can't get the right answer.

Comment: Please include sample data from the table in your question.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Please edit your question and add samples as well as edit your code.

Comment: Consider storing date and time as a single entity

Answer (score 0):

To add a `TIME` datatype value to a `DATE` datatype value, we can use an expression like this:

```
    dr.date + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC( dr.hour ) SECOND
```

The result will be value of `DATETIME` datatype.

Note that `TIME` datatype supports values of over 24 hours (up to eight hundred and some hours), so in the general case, we should anticipate that. For example, a `TIME` value such as of `284:40:35'.

Getting a substring of the first two characters of a `TIME` value is going to be problematic, considering time values of over 100 hours and less than 10 hours, e.g.  `7:11:00`. We can use the `HOUR` function to extract the hour, or iF we are going to do string manipulation, we could use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function with `:` as a delimiter.

A query like this may satisfy the specification:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( dr.date ,'%Y-%m-%d') AS date
     , TIME_FORMAT( dr.hour ,'%H'      ) AS hour
     , SUM(dr.revenue)                   AS revenue
  FROM dsp_platform_country_os_hourly_report dr 

 WHERE dr.date + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC( dr.hour ) SECOND 

       >= '2019-10-26' + INTERVAL 0 HOUR 

   AND dr.date + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC( dr.hour ) SECOND 

       <  '2019-10-26' + INTERVAL 16 HOUR 

 GROUP
    BY date
     , hour 
 ORDER
    BY date
     , hour
```

---

Alternatively, we could specify the date and hour together in the literal; using the + INTERVAL will ensure the string literal is converted to `DATETIME` datatype.

```
       >= '2019-10-26 00:00' + INTERVAL 0 DAY

       <  '2019-10-26 16:00' + INTERVAL 0 DAY
```

For larger time ranges (spanning more than a day) we probably want to consider how we handle `date` and `hour` values that result in the same `DATETIME` value

```
      '2019-10-26' + INTERVAL 30  HOURS 
      '2019-10-27' + INTERVAL 6   HOURS
```

do we want the rows with these date and hour values to be considered to be in the same bucket, or are they in two separate buckets (different date values with different hour values)

In general, we tend to avoid these types of problems by storing a `DATETIME` value in the database (with hour component restricted to less than 24), rather than storing separate `DATE` and `TIME` columns.

References:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour